# Get the domain where flash swf file is being played

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

So I want to get the domain where the flash swf is being played and not the location of the file.
If only I could get `ExternalInterface` to return the value like so:

```
var domain:String = ExternalInterface.call("document.domain");
```

But the above produces `null`....
Its an banner ad so I can't pass any `flashvars` to it or call custom `js` functions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083121/getting-domain-in-as3

Comment: No, that returns the location of the swf file. As I said I need the actual domain where the file is being played on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns `null` because you're not calling nothing:

`document.domain` is the name of a variable, not a method call.

Try `return document.domain` instead.

**EDIT:**

The correct syntax is to create an anonymous function that returns the document's domain:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

var domain:String = "";

if (ExternalInterface.available == true)
{
    try
    {
       domain = ExternalInterface.call("function() { return document.domain; }");
    }
    catch (err:Error)
    {
       domain = "Error: " + err.message;
    }

    if (domain == null) domain = "No domain"
}
```

Comment: That produces javascript error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't try it at the moment. I will check in the next 8 hours.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had time to test. I'll check it tomorrow!